# How can I save & restore GeckoView's session state?

Tags: android, mozilla, geckoview

I would like to keep the session active between orientation changes. Geckoview's documentation is lacking a bit in this area. It seems `GeckoSession` has a `restoreState` method that accepts a `SessionState`. Is there a way to create the `SessionState` object from the current state of the session?

Another approach I have tried was to create a `Parcelable` object and set this as the `SessionState` for `restoreState` but this didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the current state of a `GeckoSession` installing a `ProgressDelegate` and implementing `onSessionStateChange`, something like:

```
class ProgressDelegate extends GeckoSession.ProgressDelegate {
  @Override
  public void onSessionStateChange(GeckoSession session,
                                   SessionState sessionState) {
    // store sessionState somewhere
  }
}

ProgressDelegate delegate = new ProgressDelegate();
session.setProgressDelegate(delegate);
```